# How to use Google Maps to create polygons using routes and rivers as boundaries

Tags: google-maps

I want to develop a web app designed for mobile devices to just show some regions. These regions' boundaries consist of routes and rivers. I have no data of routes and rivers at hand, and I want to use ones provided by Google Maps.

If Google maps are not viable, please give me some tips or other ways to realize that.

Comment: Using ArcGIS to generate KML files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's forbidden to extract data from googlemap. Read the terms and agreements. Most data doesn't even belongs to Google, it is owned by GIS companies that rent it to Google.
It's not even possible to get this data using Google API. Google just provide tiles as bitmap.

This said, it's not that hard to do, just query custom tiles where everything is white but the roads and rivers. Then parse them. http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

There is another solution, the open source map database : http://www.openstreetmap.org/